Importing/appending data from a table with only new data into existing table several tables
My database has been using a form to input new records one at a time.  This input form was created automatically when the database was imported from a multi-tab Excel workbook years ago and works great. The data input form uses lookups to related tables with sub tables. For example the tblTable2 has lookups to other tables to provide lookups when entering data.  The lookups are based on a select query also automatically created when the database was converted from Excel.
Here is the query used when loading the form
SELECT Table2.DatePurchased, Table2.tblItems_ID, Table2.tblSupplier_ID, tblItems.tblCategory_ID, Table2.Price, tblItems.Notes, tblItems.Attachments, tblItems.Username, Table2.UserName AS UserName_Table2, Table2.ItemNotes
FROM tblItems INNER JOIN Table2 ON tblItems.ID = Table2.tblItems_ID;

Here are my table relationships:
https://i.sstatic.net/7oioX9ve.png
tblExcel_Import is the new table which has the data I want to import.  I am not sure where or how to put the new data and maintain table relationships.
I have tried to import into the input form using code I wrote to create a DAO recordset then using me.FormFieldName = rstrecordset method. The code loops through the the fields then goes to the next row in a while not eof loop.  The data in the retrieved rstrecordset is valid and works for the first field (unbound) date. After the Date is correctly put in the form Date field (I can see it there), I get an error the that data is not valid for the field (or close to that error) so it must relate to the next field which is a string going into a lookup field, the same as if I manually entered it.
All data in the recordset is dim'd as string variables except Date (dim'd as a date variable) and Price (dim'd as Currency). I have run a msg box loop and can see all fields and rows in the rstrecordset records and they look perfect. The code block I'm using is below. I have rem'd out several lines for testing a single pass through the recordset and to not use some debug lines used while building and testing the code originally
Private Sub Command5_Click()

' Dim'ing here
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim dRecords As Integer
Dim nRecords As Integer
Dim CountRows As String
Dim dbsBudget As DAO.Database
Dim rstPurchases As DAO.Recordset
Dim varRecords As Variant
Dim strSQL As String
Dim Field1 As Date
Dim Field2 As String
Dim Field3 As String
Dim Field4 As String
Dim Field5 As Currency
Dim Field6 As String


Set rstPurchases = Nothing
Set dbsBudget = Nothing
 
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Set and load databse and recordset
   
   Set dbsBudget = CurrentDb
   strSQL = "SELECT tblExcelImport.Date, tblExcelImport.Item, tblExcelImport.Supplier, tblExcelImport.Category, tblExcelImport.Price,tblExcelImport.Notes FROM tblExcelImport"
      'Display Count of tblExcelImport
    'nRecords = DCount("Item", "tblExcelImport", "")
    Set rstPurchases = dbsBudget.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
    'dRecords = DCount("Item", rstPurchases, "")
    'MsgBox ("Table records =" & nRecords & " Rescordset records = & " & dRecords)
    
    ' While Not rstPurchases.EOF (Update single form test (no loooping through recordset for now)
   'MsgBox ("Row ") & Counter & "= " & rstPurchases(0) & ", " & rstPurchases(1) & ", " & rstPurchases(2) & ", " & rstPurchases(3) & ", " & rstPurchases(4) & ", " & rstPurchases(5)

   ' Field definitions for later debugiign if needed:
   ' Field1 DatePurchased
   ' Field2 tblItems_ID
   ' Field3 tblSupplier_ID
   ' Field4 tblCategory_ID
   ' Field5 Price
   ' Field6 Notes

   ' assign rstfields to Field variables
    
    Field1 = rstPurchases(0)
    Field2 = rstPurchases(1)
    Field3 = rstPurchases(2)
    Field4 = rstPurchases(3)
    Field5 = rstPurchases(4)
    Field6 = rstPurchases(5)
    
    
    ' DoCmd.OpenForm "AddExpenseImport" - since this sub is called onClick while form is open this is probably not needed
    
    MsgBox ("Row = " & Field1 & ", " & Field2 & ", " & Field3 & ", " & Field4 & ", " & Field5 & ", " & Field6)
    ' I can see that the Fields are correct for the the row
    
    'For testing populate form fields for first recordset row only then stop
    
    Me![DatePurchased] = Field1 ' this line works
    ' error occurs on next line
    Me!tblItems_ID = Field2
    ' Error = "The value your entered isn't valid for this field"
    ' When the form isn't being populated by the VBA code I can enter exactly the same data manually without error
    Me!tblSupplier_ID = Field3
    Me!tblCategory_ID = Field4
    Me!Price = Field5
    Me![ItemNotes] = Field6
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
Stop ' added for testing only
   'rstPurchases.MoveNext
   'Counter = Counter + 1 - for debugging
   'Wend rem'd out for single pass only

 
   Set rstPurchases = Nothing
   Set dbsBudget = Nothing
   Exit Sub
 
ErrorHandler:   MsgBox ("Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description)


End Sub

After several iterations of trying to fix the DAO code block, I gave up and thought that an Append routine might be better but that exceeds my knowledge level of proper use with multiple table with subtables.
Any help with helping to debug my DAO loop and/or help with understanding how to use an Append or other method to add data to my existing tables would be greatly appreciated.
